# Drupal on custom page?

Tags: users

I created a .php page outside of Drupal. On that page I want to check if a user is logged into my Drupal site.

Is that possible?

Comment: This is really an unsupported way of Drupal.

Answer (score 6):

If the PHP file is in the same directory where cron.php, and index.php files from Drupal installation are, then you can use the following code.

```
/**
 * Root directory of Drupal installation.
 */
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
include_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL); 

if (user_is_logged_in()) {
  //...
}
```

If the PHP file is in another directory, then you should use the following code.

```
/**
 * Root directory of Drupal installation.
 */
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', 'the directory containing the includes directory from Drupal');
include_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL); 

if (user_is_logged_in()) {
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Then you need to include these lines at top of your file

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());

include_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

Then use the following code to check if the user is logged in or not,

```
global $user;
if ($user->uid) {
// User is logged in
}
```

For anonymous user uid will be 0.